# Defining coordinate system for finding distance in meters

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, epsg, hadoop, spatial-framework-hadoop

What should I do to find the distance between two very far points?

```
p1 = "POINT(6.2 61.1)"
p2 = "POINT(6.1 61.0)"

select
ST_Distance(
  ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromWKT('$p1'), 'EPSG:4326', '$epsg'),
  ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromWKT('$p2'), 'EPSG:4326', '$epsg')
) as distance
```

with `EPSG:3857` this is `25550.25`
but with `EPSG:32632` I'm got `12382.11` and leaning on Google that's right.

I'm using GeoSpark library in my calculations.

Update: My range of longitude approximately from 20 to 190

Update 2: I can't use PostGIS, I'm using Hadoop and GeoSpark

Comment: The main idea is to use [Projected CS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//003r0000000p000000.htm) which can be local or worldwide. By the way, where your points should be located, i.e. country? Probably some reprojection is needed.

Comment: Points can be located from whole all Russia, I didn't find any projection which covers it.

In global, my objective is find nieghbors polygons in 500 meters, where I use epsg:3856, and then precise distance with local EPSG which i find with that function:
`val epsgCode: Geometry => String = { g =>
    val lat: Double = g.getCentroid.getX;

     return s"EPSG:${32631 + (lat / 6).toInt}"
  }`

Comment: 0.1 difference in X and Y isn't generally considered "very far", even in geographic units. Try using the coordinates of London and Christchurch, at which point even a projected coordinate system can't help. Web Mercator (3857) should never be used for Cartesian distance calculations. Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification.

Comment: I've wrote sample, that shows that I have problems even with so close points. My range of longitude approximately from 20 to -170

Comment: Given the range of longitudes, you're probably better off using a geodetic library which will compute great elliptical values on the spheroid.

Comment: Take a look at ST_GeodesicLengthWGS84 for Hive & SparkSQL - https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/UDF-Accessors#st_geodesiclengthwgs84 [disclosure: collaborator]